# Is it possible to use templates when creating a scratch file in PyCharm?

Tags: templates, pycharm, scratch-file

I created a custom template file and I can use it from the "File"->"New..." menu option.

But I was expecting to see it also when creating a new scratch file using
"File"->"New Scratch File"

Is this even possible?

(I am using PyCharm 2017.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible: each time you create a scratch file, it's created from *scratch*.

Though, what's possible in order to simplify your life, is using [`Live Templates`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/live-templates.html): you can create your own abbreviation, which can be expanded automatically to some portion of code. There are many examples in `Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates` so you can use them as an example.

Comment: The alternative of using Live Templates is good enough for my needs. Thanks for the suggestion